# Evaluating limits using Taylor's expansion.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Evaluate the following limit : $\lim_{x \to 0}(\frac{1}{\log(\cos(x))}+\frac{2}{\sin^2(x)})$

Generally speaking I have no idea at what order should I stop the Taylor's expansion.
I've tried this using two different orders and i've gotten both the results 1 and 0.

If anyone could point out how I should pick the order of the expansion i would be grateful!

Comment: This is not a problem about Taylor expansions since you would start with negative powers of $x$. It's a Laurent expansion. That said, compute all terms up to and including order 0, since terms involving $x^{-k}$ must cancel if there is to be a finite limit. The correct answer is 1.

Comment: You try until you find an expansion which is not reduced to its error term. When you're not sure, you  can try a three-terms expansion.

Comment: you can do Taylor expansion for the denominator to the 4th order.

Comment: How did you know you should stop at the 4th order?

Comment: When you take a pencil and do it, you see where you can stop. If you wait for a copy/paste-ready solution, you don't.

Comment: I've already tried solving this as i've mentionned in the post and i've gotten two results, I'm not waiting for any copy/paste solutions as i know they wouldn't benefit me ,thus  in my question I didn't ask to solve the limit , I asked for a way to find out at what order should the expansion stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$ \ln(\cos x) = \ln\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^4)\right) = -\left( \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^4) \right) $$

$$ \frac{\sin^2 x}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(x + O(x^3) \right)^2 = \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^4) $$

When you add the inverses, the first terms will cancel out. You will need to expand up to the $x^4$ coefficient to find the limit.

**EDIT:** You can write the inverses in the form

$$ \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)} = \frac{2}{x^2}\frac{1}{1+O(x^2)} $$

and expand the geometric series, which will show that all terms past $x^4$ go to zero.

Comment: I did expand to the 2nd order and i've gotten the result 0 , I didn't know if i should expand more or just stop , but now that i've seen your answer I think the problem is solved. Very helpful!

Comment: Note that you can't make any conclusion if only a finite number of terms cancel. All terms in the series need to be $0$ for the limit to be $0$

Comment: Noted! I'll be sure to get the right order now.

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt should be to simplify the expression rather than start working out the Taylor series. You can observe that the expression can be written as $$2\left(\frac{1}{\log(1-\sin^{2}x)}+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}x}\right)$$ and putting $t=\sin^{2}x$ it can be written more compactly as $$2\cdot\frac{t+\log(1-t)}{t\log(1-t)}$$ or $$2\cdot\frac{t+\log(1-t)}{t^{2}}\cdot\frac{t}{\log(1-t)}$$ The last factor tends to $-1$ as $t\to 0^{+}$ and hence we need to evaluate the limit of $$-2\cdot\frac{t+\log(1-t)}{t^{2}}$$ And now the answer to your question is obvious. Just get the Taylor series for $\log(1-t)$ from your memory as $$-t-\frac{t^{2}}{2}+o(t^{2})$$ (thus expansion upto order $2$ is needed) and the answer is immediately seen to be $1$.

Comment: If you could please tell me what was the used simplification I’d appreciate it!

Comment: Nvm I found it out!

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\log(\cos(x))}+\frac{2}{\sin^2(x)}\right)=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2x+2\ln\cos x}{\sin^2x\ln\cos x}$$

We can stop Taylor's expansion at the denominator to the first (different from zero) term, because it's a product and nothing is going to cancel. So if $x$ tends to $0$ we have

$$\sin^2x\ln\sin x=\left(x^2+o(x^2)\right)\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right)=\left(x^2+o(x^2)\right)\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)\right)=$$

$$=-\frac{x^4}{2}+o(x^4)$$

So we need $x^4$ "precision" on the numerator too, to avoid approximation errors. Hence

$$\sin^2x+2\ln\cos x=\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)\right)^2+2\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+o(x^4)\right)=$$

$$=x^2-\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^4}{3}+o(x^4)+2\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2+o(x^4)\right)$$

So finally we have

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\log(\cos(x))}+\frac{2}{\sin^2(x)}\right)=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{-\frac{x^4}{2}+o(x^4)}{-\frac{x^4}{2}+o(x^4)}=1$$